# how to change the href attribute according to the child using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have several paragraphs in one page. each title is marked by an automatically generated id.

Example:

```
<h3 id="One">Title 1</h3>
<h3 id="Two">Title 2</h3>
<h3 id="Tree">Title 3</h3>
<h3 id="Foor">Title 4</h3>
```

Using the jquery, I created a parent for each title. the code is below:

```
$(function () {
    $('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content > h3').wrap("<a class='blockLink'></a>");
});
```

the output now is:

```
<a class="blockLink"><h3 id="One">Title 1</h3></a>
<a class="blockLink"><h3 id="Two">Title 2</h3></a>
<a class="blockLink"><h3 id="Tree">Title 3</h3></a>
<a class="blockLink"><h3 id="Foor">Title 4</h3></a>
```

What I want now is add the href attribute for each anchor based on the id attribute in each title, as below:

```
<a href="#One" class="blockLink"><h3 id="One">Title 1</h3></a>
<a href="#Two" class="blockLink"><h3 id="Two">Title 2</h3></a>
```

....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each of your headers, grab its id, and use it for for the link that you wrap each one with.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vamomereme/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
$(function () {  
  $('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content > h3').each(function(index,ele){
    var $this = $(ele);
    var id = $this.attr('id');

    $this.wrap("<a class='blockLink' href='#".concat(id,"'></a>"));
  });
});
```

Comment: or just `href='#" + id + "'></a>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the anonymous function of the `wrap()` method:

```js
$(function() {
  // because we don't have the surrounding HTML I've
  // simplified the selector; obviously this will need
  // to be adjusted in production:
  $('h3').wrap(function() {
    // here we return a template-literal of the HTML with
    // which you wish to surround the 'this' (the current
    // <h3> element. The JavaScript enclosed within the
    // '${...}' is parsed and interpolated into the resulting
    // template literal:
    return `<a href="#${this.id}" class="blockLink"></a>`;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="One">Title 1</h3>
<h3 id="Two">Title 2</h3>
<h3 id="Tree">Title 3</h3>
<h3 id="Foor">Title 4</h3>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z35sqaLn/).

Note, however, that while this answer does give you what you ask for, it might not be what you *want*; as an anchor element with `href="#one"` will link to an element with an `id` of `one`; which is the element that the `<a>` element is wrapping in this HTML structure.

If you can clarify your intent, then we may be able to assist further; this may be as simple as adjusting the template-literal to something as simple as:

```
return `<a href="#section_${this.id}" class="blockLink"></a>`;
// <a href="#section_One" class="blockLink">
//   <h3 id="One">Title 1</h3>
// </a>
```

- JavaScript:

  - [template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- jQuery
- [`wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/).